# how can i refresh after deleting the record in kendo grid through Context menu in angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, kendo-grid

how can i refresh after deleting the record in kendoui grid through Context menu  in angular 2

note after Calling this delete() method(Api) then iwant to refresh Specific grid

```
Delete() {
        if (this.Index != null) {
            this.headers = new Headers();
            this.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            this.RecuNum = '1';
            this.http.post('/BizApi/Delete', JSON.stringify(this.RecuNum), { headers: this.headers })
                .map(response => response.json())
                .subscribe(result => {
                    //var Deleterec = result[0];

                    this.router.navigate(['/Home/AListing']);
                },
                err => console.log(err)
                );
            this.Products();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can go with `this.router.navigateByUrl('/component', true);`

Comment: hi  Liyaquet Hussain it is not working.

Comment: i thought by using this.view.Splice(index,1) we can achive this